When loading from a file, the .observe and .on_click functions don't work on a rerun of the cell
I'm using IPyWidgets in a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code. When making an interface, I use a .py file to code and load this into the notebook. This looks like the following:
import Moduals.TestFile as File

display(File.button)

Where the testfile looks as follows:
import ipywidgets as widgets

button = widgets.Button(description="Click me")

def F_button(PlacHolder = None):
    print("Press")

button.on_click(F_button)

This works fine until I need to reload the cell in the notebook. After doing this, the .observe and .on_click methods don't register any input. After the kernel is reloaded, the functions work again until you reload the cell without reloading the kernel.
I expected .observe to work the second time, but even after resetting all global variables, the problem persists. I suspect that the button might be renamed because the same occurs when using the code from the test file in a notebook and display(button) is in a second cell. If the first cell is reloaded, the button is not recognized until I rerun the second cell.

I'm having a hard time following what you mean by 'reload the cell'? Related, but sort of separate: I think you start getting to the minimal situation where you start writing, " I suspect that the button might be renamed because the same occurs when using the code from the test file in a notebook and display(button) is in a second cell. If the first cell is reloaded, the button is not recognized until I rerun the second cell." But you don't provide code for that?  Separate but related: def F_button(PlacHolder = None) doesn't look typical to me. You mention the .observe but I don't see one?

 A minimal , reproducible example would be better for the test file in a notebook case, I think. Then we can get back to the more complicated situation that you start out with here. Back to 'big picture' things...the statement, "After the kernel is reloaded, the functions work again until you reload the cell without reloading the kernel" confuses me, too? What specifically do you mean. You mean restarting the kernel? And then similar to my first question what do you mean by 'reload the cell' there?

when using a jupyter notebook you can make pyton cells, theas can be loaded individually. zo the code provided for testfile.py can be put in one cell en the next cell contains the display(button). theas can be played per codecell

Okay, I did that. If I run the two cells and press the button a few times. All good:  I see Press go to my JupyterLab LogFile because you don't have output handling in your minimal code. If I then re-run only the first cell, that has the testfile contents, it works fine. I can keep pressing the button and see Press go to my JupyterLab LogFile still. Not seeing what you are saying. Or I'm not doing what you do? I am testing here. Click 'launch binder' there. You need to click the blue LogFile symbol at the bottom...

, along the very bottom ribbon of JupyterLab in the bottom left corner area, after pressing the button.  (And of course, the second cell was actually display(button).)
